# What purpose has the method IStreamProvider.ReleaseStream?

Tags: c#, .net

The interface **System.Xml.IStreamProvider** has two methods:

- **GetStream** (MSDN: This method can be used to return the stream to be written)
- **ReleaseStream** (MSDN: Releases a stream to output)

I understand the purpose of the GetStream method but I don't understand what to do with ReleaseStream. Am I supposed to call Dispose() inside ReleaseStream ?

Comment: You can go through [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/StreamFormatter.cs,358) yourself, but it doesn't seem to have an implementation anywhere.

Comment: `ReleaseStream` is for giving ownership of the stream that you obtained with `GetStream` back to the provider. FWIW, I don't think you need to do this before you dispose.

Comment: Think of it as reference counting (albeit with a count of at most 1) -- `GetStream` lays a claim and `ReleaseStream` indicates that the stream is no longer in use by the client. That does not generally mean you dispose the stream immediately in `ReleaseStream`, because that would imply all serialization is done, which is generally not something the provider decides (unless you've combined it with the serialization itself, of course). Tracing out the calls to these methods while serializing may provide more clarity.

Comment: Just imagine that this stream is provided by a file or web server.  GetStream is obvious, open the file or connect to the server.  But you always have to undo this again; close the file, disconnect.  That is what ReleaseStream is expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are two internal types in the .NET Framework that I know of that implements this interface - `ByteStreamStreamProvider` and `OperationStreamProvider` in the `System.ServiceModel` namespace. Neither of them do anything in the `ReleaseStream` method. It's implemented like this in both cases:

```
public void ReleaseStream(Stream stream)
{
    //Noop
}
```

So depending on your implementation you don't have to do anything.

Comment: *So depending on your implementation you don't have to do anything.* That is true for 90% of all methods.

Comment: Maybe. But an interface doesn't define *how* a method should be implemented. You get a stream and you should return nothing. The rest is entirely up to the implementation. So what to do in `ReleaseStream` does depend on the implementation of the class.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question what the method is for. But from the comments to the question itself I understand that calling ReleaseStream is supposed to signal that the Stream is no longer needed.

Comment: @DiegoDeberdt: As the name implies, the method is for releasing the stream. What this means is decided by the implementation.